# Why does Grails/Hibernate create my column as type Long?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am upgrading my app from Grails 1.3.7 to 2.0.1.  Given this domain class,

```
class Person {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        name type: 'text'
    }
}
```

I expect the 'name' column in my Oracle database to be a CLOB, as it was under 1.3.7.  Instead, it's of type Long, which causes all sorts of problems.

I am using the Oracle OJDBC driver (ojdbc6:11.1.0.7.0).  For run-app purposes, I'm connecting to an Oracle XE instance; I have no reason to expect that I'll get different behavior running agains an Oracle 11g database.  My dataSource driverClassName is "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
static mapping = {
    name sqlType: 'clob'
}
```

I do not know how to reconcile the information on this page:

[type](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html)

with the information on this page:

[columns](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html)

...but at least it works.